# How to create a working sidebar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Recently I was following a [speedcode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krU-ASLb8lM) of a guy and finish it.

And then I see that the code "appBar" is using a class [the screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJdfa.png). It's different than any tutorial I found, so I modified the class to add the sidebar(**drawer**), its working fine but there's a problem.

The sidebar is on bottom floor, the body is on second floor. You will understand with screenshot below

[this is before I click the sidebar button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHDQQ.png)

[this is after I click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FulsT.png)

**This is the main screen code:**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String _country = 'ID';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          _buildHeader(screenHeight),
          _buildPreventionTips(screenHeight),
          _buildYourOwnTest(screenHeight),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**And this is the custombarapp code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:covid_19_master/config/palette.dart';

class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('this is appbar'),
        backgroundColor: Palette.primaryColor,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(child: Text('ini header ya')),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('ini listnya'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('ini listnya'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('ini listnya'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('ini listnya'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the *Drawer* widget, but from looking at the docs. I don't think it should be inside the *appBar*, but it should be in its own 'main property'   https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `CustomAppBar()`, it has its own `Scaffold()`, which comes under another `Scaffold()` in your parent Class that is `HomeScreen()`. Avoid this type of thing, because *Flutter StatefulWidget cannot have nested Scaffolds*.

Do not make things complex. Rather use your `AppBar()` and `Drawer()` in the same `HomePage` itself, with a property `AppBar()` and `Drawer()` respectively. Then use it inside your view.

**MainPage**

Look at the comments as well to get the full picture, and you will be good :)

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String _country = 'ID';

  // Appbar code with Appbar Data Type
  Appbar _customAppBar() => AppBar(
    title: Text('this is appbar'),
    backgroundColor: Palette.primaryColor,
    elevation: 0.0,
  );

  // Drawer widget with Drawer property
  Drawer _customDrawer() => Drawer(
     child: ListView(
       children: <Widget>[
         DrawerHeader(child: Text('ini header ya')),
         ListTile(
           title: Text('ini listnya'),
         ),
         ListTile(
           title: Text('ini listnya'),
         ),
         ListTile(
           title: Text('ini listnya'),
         ),
         ListTile(
           title: Text('ini listnya'),
         )
       ]
     )
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      // use it here with Preferred size
      appBar: PreferredSizeWidget(
         preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
         child: _customAppBar() // your appabr
      ),
      // your drawer
      drawer: _customDrawer(),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          _buildHeader(screenHeight),
          _buildPreventionTips(screenHeight),
          _buildYourOwnTest(screenHeight),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great @YovanGaming Keep up the good work! Make this app functional and launch it on PlayStore and Apple Store with some of your changes which you think can be good and unique. All the very best mate! :)